# Regularly Download something from database over the Internet in background

Tags: android, service, background, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app.
I want the program **Regularly** Download something from database over the Internet **in background**.

Should I use AlarmManager to trigger the BroadcastReceiver to download data from database?

Or there is other better method? Please give me some keywords to google if there is.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` is supposed to be pretty short lived, so you're better off starting up a `Service` to download, but using the `AlarmManager` to trigger the whole process is probably the way to go.

Comment: Can I just start a thread in BroadcastReceiver to do the long task? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a Service that download the data from internet periodically with a thread.

You should have a "Application" class or something to access the DB of your app on the service, and then update all the data.

Services run in background mode.